# Why does this filter function return the value error?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, office365

In the formula below, a #Value! error is returned.

```
=FILTER(FIND(";"&AS4756:AS4762&{6,7},AG4756),ISNUMBER(FIND(";"&AS4756:AS4762&{6,7},AG4756)))
```

Where ag4756 is `8034000;Y8033343543543;Y;38918;BS7 9XL;9;Male;N;N;N`

and AS4756:AS4762 is

```
BS
NP
SN
GL
BA
CF
TA
```

When I chose evaluate formula, it returns the number 31 for the string BS7, and errors for all others. I'm trying to filter out the errors from the result, so I only get the result which is not an error. It also correctly returns TRUE for BS7, and false for all the others. But then the next step results in the error. Can anyone help?

edit: I want to return the position of the substring that starts with BS7. Or BS6, or NP6, or NP7, and so on.

Comment: What is it you really want to do here? End up with a number to indicate the position of a possible substring? Or with the actual substrings that match?

Comment: I've edited to clarify that I want to return the position of the substring that starts with BS7. Or BS6, or NP6, or NP7, and so on. However, if you know, it would be helpful to understand why my Filter version didn't work, as I'm new to these dynamic array formulas and they're very useful and powerful. Thanks

Comment: Ok - but if my formula excludes the numbers in the curly braces, it does work - despite FIND resulting in an array that contains errors. In fact evaluating it looks exactly the same up until the end result, which returns 31 without the number criteria, and #VALUE! with the number criteria

Comment: IOW if the formula is =FILTER(FIND(";"&AS4756:AS4762,AG4756),ISNUMBER(FIND(";"&AS4756:AS4762,AG4756))) it works without any issue at all. Other than having criteria in curly braces nothing is different, so I don't get why it works in one case and not the other. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I hope the following helps you out a bit; let's assume data (vertical) `{BS;NP;SN;GL;BA;CF;TA}` to be in `A1:A7` and the lookup-string to be in `B1`. You are then concatenating a 2nd (horizontal) array `{6,7}` which would make up the following matrix:

[image]

Now to find these values in `B1` using `FIND(";"&A1:A7&{6,7},C1)` would result in:

[image]

The next step for you would be to gather the numeric value. However, for the 2nd parameter, you have provided a 7*2 **matrix** and not a 1D-vertical *or* horizontal array of values. Therefor `FILTER()` will error out on exactly **that** step, returning the '#VALUE!'! And even so, if you would try to use `MMULT()` tricks to retrieve this array correctly you'd still need to deal with the fact you are trying to filter a matrix from the 1st parameter that is filled with errors. Therefor, I've shown how you could get the position from a relative easy formula that would deal with errors too:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(FIND(";"&A1:A7&{6,7},B1),""))
```

And to get the correct substring, use:

```
=MID(B1,MAX(IFERROR(FIND(";"&A1:A7&{6,7},B1)+1,"")),3)
```

Now that leaves us with the probability you have more potential substrings you'd like to be returned. If that is the case, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, that formula works. And I didn't realise that it mattered about the dimensionality (correct word?) of the array, now I do.